# how to return an array-list from a actionListener and then call it to another actionListener?

Tags: java, arraylist, return, return-value, actionlistener

Right now I basically have this:

```
class ConvertButtonListener implements ActionListener 
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) 
    {
        //Do stuff
        ArrayList<String> blah = new ArrayList<String>();
        blah.add(item);
    }
}
```

I need to use it in another action listener:

```
class UploadButtonListener implements ActionListener {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                ArrayList<String> attachmentFileListUpload = new ArrayList<String>();
                getAttachmentFileList(attachmentFileListUpload);
                JFrame uploadFrame = new UploadFrame(attachmentFileList);
                //UploadFrame is a seperate class that extends JFrame
            }
        }
```

And then I have this

```
public ArrayList<String> returnAttachmentFileList(ArrayList<String> attachmentFileList)
    {
        return attachmentFileList;
    }
public ArrayList<String> getAttachmentFileList(ArrayList<String> attachmentFileListUpload)
    {
        attachmentFileListUpload = attachmentFileList.clone();
    }
```

I know I could find a way to make it final and have it work and it would be alot easier but I feel like This is something Important I will need to learn eventually. Would I absolutely need to put the methods in a different class?

Edit: I'm still researching, Would I need to declare the ArrayList in another class then just extend the .add() method?

What I'm doing is taking files that I retrieve in the ConvertButtonListener and saving their base64 content and filename in 2 different arrays, for the uploadButtonListener I need it to be able to see if there where any files(This is alot of code so and taking it and adjusting it for the other actionListener will take hours so I am trying to stick it in an array and return it) so I want to check to see if the array is null, If it is not null I pass the array to a new frame and and scan the entire file (I put the whole file in a string) for the contents of the old file then replace it with the base64 content of the new file that will be uploaded.

Comment: Why do you need 2 arraylists to store the values, can you use a MAP to store the key/value (base64 value / Filename)?

Comment: Maybe you can make your own ActionEvent with as source the ArrayList (or so). And then `AwtEventQueue.invokeLater calling the other actionPerformed.

Comment: The map thing is a very very good idea! But I would still have the issue of having to use the arraymap in another class.

Comment: I added some more sample code to my first post to clarify how you can approach the problem. You could easily modify that to use Map instead of ArrayList<String>.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to see if I could do it without making it it's own class but I guess this still gives me alot to mess around with. I appreciate the help! One more question though, Would i be able to add to it within the Action Listener without having to extend the .add()/.put() method?

Comment: the .add() method is a basic List method thats provided by Java Collections framework, to add something to a list, you will need to call it. How you populate the list is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to determine exactly what you're trying to do based on the code sample, but if you're just looking to pass around a list, why not use a singleton object that represents the list and pass that around instead of worrying about creating a new one, getting/setting, etc.

Sample Singleton:

```
public final class MyArrayList {

private static MyArrayList myArrayList = null;
private List<String> aListOfSomething = new ArrayList<String>();

private MyArrayList() {
}

// Global access point with lazy instantiation
public static MyArrayList getInstance() {
    if (myArrayList == null) {
        myArrayList = new MyArrayList();
    }
    return myArrayList;
}

public List<String> getMyList() {
    return aListOfSomething;
}

}
```

Then in either of your classes, you could call it like this.

```
    MyArrayList.getInstance().getMyList().add("File1");
    MyArrayList.getInstance().getMyList().add("File2");
    MyArrayList.getInstance().getMyList().add("File3");
```

Note this singleton is very basic, advanced implementation can be found here: www.jasonsjavadocs.com

Here's another bit of code that might help...

```
class ConvertButtonListener implements ActionListener {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

    MyArrayList.getInstance().getMyList().clear();
    MyArrayList.getInstance().getMyList().add("Item1");
    MyArrayList.getInstance().getMyList().add("Item2");
    MyArrayList.getInstance().getMyList().add("Item3");

}
}


class UploadButtonListener implements ActionListener {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

    if (MyArrayList.getInstance().getMyList().isEmpty()) {
        // do nothing
    } else {
        // pass array to new frame
    }

}
}
```

Comment: I edited to say what I am doing, I know very little about returning from classes. I need the Arrays to be updated in the convert-listener depndent on what files they bring back and then I need to be able to take those Arrays and use them in my uploadListener. If you need any clarification just ask! I know making them final would make this alot easier but I feel like this is something big that I should learn rather then ignoring it.

Answer (score 0):

In `ActionListener` we do override method `public void actionPerformed()` As it has return type of void, so it **cannot return** anything, as you are asking in your question.

What you can do is, make your list an instance variable or class variable, then set its value in the actionPerformed method.

Then you can access it via object (if instance variable) or via class name (if class variable) in any other listener.

```
class Demo{
     ArrayList<WHATEVER> list = null;

    .....

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
          //Do What you want
          list.add(STUFF);
    }
}
```

The list in the above class is instance variable so can be used in any other class/listener via object of this class.

Comment: I'm not trying to return anything frmo the ActionListener, I'm trying to make a method that will save the value and allow me to use it in a different ActionListener. I'm starting to think It would have to be it's own class though